# "Will I" vs. "I will"

Tags: word-choice

As in the following sentence:

> When I have the time, I will watch a new episode of one of the aforementioned Netflix shows, though rarely **I will** watch one of the shows below:

vs.

> When I have the time, I will watch a new episode of one of the aforementioned Netflix shows, though rarely **will I** watch one of the shows below:

Comment: Subject-auxiliary inversion (which is the technical term for changing _I will_ to _will I_) is required in yes-no questions, and is optional in several situations. This is one; when a negative adverb (like _rarely_) is moved to the beginning of the sentence, it is possible (but not necessary) to invert the subject and the first auxiliary. But this **only** works with negative adverbs that negate the whole sentence; try it with _often_ instead of _rarely_ to see what happens when the rule is violated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I have the time, I will watch a new episode of one of the aforementioned Netflix shows, though rarely **will** I watch one of the shows below

Is the one I would choose, though in this particular sentence each is acceptable.